# jQuery Masonry create a "clear:both" break in layout ( last $item as footer )

Tags: jquery

any advice if is it possible to create a page break inside the container? (this is quite strange...)

You would like something a 100% width last $item that always stay left:0px (something like a footer).

Layout is responsive so i cannot give it a fixed width.

thank you

Comment: Page-breaks are for printing. Is this what you're after?